# Forcing an item to remain in place in a jQuery UI Sortable list

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I've set up a jQuery sortable list but I need to be able to keep some items in the sortable 'fixed' in place and for the other items to sort around them. I thought that there would be built in methods to achieve this, alas this is not the case.

I'm able to set up the list and not include the items in question:

```
<ul id="fruit">
    <li class="fixed">apples</li>
    <li>oranges</li>
    <li>bananas</li>
    <li>pineapples</li>
    <li>grapes</li>
    <li class="fixed">pears</li>
    <li>mango</li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#fruit').sortable({items: "li:not('.fixed')"})
</script>
```

This stops me from drag/dropping these items but they still move if the items around them are sorted. There may be a way to do this using the many callbacks that this method has but I've been unable to work this out.

Maybe this method would be a good addition to the UI Sortable options?

Comment: I could see if they were all at the top or bottom of the list -- but I'd have to wonder how it would work if you sorted with your list -- would pears still be second from the last, or fixed in relationship to the one before it  (I can see a use for the second one, can't think of a situation for the first one)?  Can someone drag mango above pears, and then sort it, would pears now stay last in the list?

Comment: They would stay in the same position (index) and only the items around them would change. I asked a question 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519103/how-can-i-sort-an-array-yet-exclude-certain-elements-to-be-kept-at-the-same-pos

That has a similar theme to this one (although in that case, simply sorting arrays) - however the principle is the same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to do this by modifying jitters code a bit, and attach it to the "change" event rather than the "stop". I did it by looking how the index changes when dragging an item around and set up some conditionals. It also works with multiple fixed elements. The "lockto" variable defines the positon of the fixed element, and the fixed element should be in this position initially. You could probably rewrite this and wrap it in a function so you don't need to manually set the "lockto" variable for all fixed elements.

```
$("#sortable").sortable({
    "cancel":"li.static",
    "change":function(event,ui) {
        var lockto = 6;
        var thisindex = $(ui.helper).index(fixed);         
        var fixed = $("#static-"+lockto);           
        var index = $("#sortable li").index(fixed);
        var targetindex = lockto+1;
        if(index !== targetindex) {         
            if(index > targetindex ) {
                fixed.prev().insertAfter(fixed); //move it up by one position
            } else if(index==(targetindex-1) && thisindex>targetindex) {
                //don't move it at all
            } else {
                fixed.next().insertBefore(fixed); //move it down by one position
            }
        } else if(index==targetindex && thisindex>targetindex) {
            fixed.prev().insertAfter(fixed); //move it up by one position
        }       
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response - I will try to test this out when I get a spare 10 minutes ;-)

Comment: @tester testers Thanks your code is working fine with single fixed element but it is not working fine with multiple fixed element.

please check link http://jsfiddle.net/shuklendu/hP4rm/4/
In above link I want Item 2, Item 4 and Item 6 should remain in their place while sorting.

Drag Item 7 up towards Item 1 and check Item 4 and Item 6 will change their position.

Answer (score 1):

This is non trivial I guess. For your example it's still feasible with a little work (a generic solution would be a bit harder)

Check http://jsbin.com/etubi/2 for a demo (http://jsbin.com/etubi/2/edit for the code)

```
$("#sortable").sortable({
    cancel: "li.fixed", //exclude fixed ones
    stop:function(event, ui) {
        //nothing to do for #f0 as you can't sort anything above it
        var f5 = $("#f5");
        var indf5 = $("#sortable li").index(f5);
        //if f5 not in right position -> swap position
        if(indf5 !== 5) {
            if(indf5 > 5) {
                f5.prev().insertAfter(f5); //move it up by one position
            } else {
                f5.next().insertBefore(f5); //move it down by one position
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer.

This solution will work for me, however there is still the problem of the items appearing to move during the sort (which is fixed when the sort has finished).

A *perfect* solution would mean that the item stays fixed (visually) while the sort is taking place. With the number of event handlers available I think this may be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Wish I had seen this question before I posted mine and did all that Sortable research. This could have been a good starting point. Anyway, here's [JQuery Sortable set item to an index programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928002/jquery-sortable-set-item-to-an-index-programmatically) a generic solution to this problem.