# JQuery sortable list with some elements frozen in order?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am looking for a method to have a JQuery-like sortable list ([link](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/)), but with some of the elements in fixed undraggable positions.

It's trivial to make some elements undraggable, but their positions don't remain fixed because the number of draggable elements above and below them can change.

To be more specific:
I have a list of 10 items in rank order.   I want the user to be able to change the rank for some of the items by dragging (a la sortable list), but not change the rank of other frozen elements.  The standard JQuery sortable undraggable feature allows the rank of frozen items to be changed by changing the number of elements above or below the frozen ones.

I've tried do this manually by "swapping" list elements when dragging.  I.e., when a list element is dragged over a non-frozen element, the position of the two elements is swapped.  This gives the semantics I want, but the item being dragged visibly "jumps" between its new position and the current 'drag' position. (I want it to remain in its current drag position; only its position in the DOM should change.  But when the DOM position changes, the drag offset coordinates must be recomputed.  And I don't know how to do both the DOM position change and drag offset coordinate change atomically, preventing a redraw between the two.  Currently, sometimes a redraw happens between the two, and the element visibly, albeit shortly, jumps.)

**Edit**
Here's a jsfiddle showing my manual approach:
[link](http://jsfiddle.net/xP8hW/1/).  Play with it for a while and you'll notice the flicker/jumping I mentioned.

Comment: Have you tried binding your behaviour to the `beforeStop` event?

Comment: This sounds pretty interesting, and I gather you already have some almost-working code? Please consider creating a jsfiddle with what you've got!

Comment: @LinusGThiel, I added a link to a jsfiddle showing my manual attempt.

Comment: @graphicdivine, can you expand on that?  What behavior should I add on `beforeStop`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've looked at your fiddle, had another think, and here's one way to do it using `sortable`: on `start` store the fixed index positions in the `data` object of each fixed item, and then on any `change`, move the fixed items back into place.

```
$(function() {   
    $('#rankings').sortable({
        axis: 'y',
        items: '.sortable',
        start: function () {
            $(this).find("li:not(.sortable)").each(function () {
                $(this).data("fixedIndex", $(this).index());
            });
        },        
        change: function () {
            $(this).find("li:not(.sortable)").each(function () {
                $(this).detach().insertAfter($("#rankings li:eq(" + ($(this).data("fixedIndex")-1) + ")"));
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Using a list such as:

```
<ol id="rankings">
    <li class="sortable">Dog</li>
    <li class="">Cat</li>
    <li class="sortable">Parrot</li>
    <li class="sortable">Gerbil</li>
    <li class="sortable">Snake</li>
    <li class="">Goldfish</li>
</ol>
```

[Seems to work](http://jsfiddle.net/Q8wHS/).

Comment: I suppose for more efficiency you might also want to check whether the non-sortable items are out of place *before* you detach and move them.

Comment: Nice; this is the cleanest solution so far.  All the reshuffling leads to an occasional stutter, but for small lists it's not too noticeable.

Comment: This fails if the first item in the list is not sortable, because you would try to insertAfter index -1.  [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6131590/379428) adds a dummy element.  Ick.

Comment: Simpler solution: just check for fixedIndex 0 and skip it.  Sortable wouldn't move that element in the first place.  A check for fixedIndex  == $(this).index() does the same thing.

Comment: +1. Excellent. Solved my problem. I actually was just looking for the `items: '.sortable'` part, but the whole solution is quite interesing.

Comment: I had to figure out a way to force a div to stay at the end that allows you to 'add new' to the parent div, and came up with this (based on your answer, thanks!):

`change: function () { $(this).find(".addNewAgentDiv").detach().insertAfter($(this).children("div").last()); }`

Answer (score 4):

I think I might have cracked it - http://jsfiddle.net/q5c4Y/3/. Quite a challenge though. A few things helped along the way

- Using more structured markup
- Using droppable's over event to swap list items, but not the drop event (using dragstop instead)
- Setting some positioning on inner items in order to keep them in the right position after changing their parent element

Although, reading @graphicdivine's answer above, it looks like what you really needed all along is jquery ui sortable

Comment: Interesting. This solution is still somewhat broken, because an item can't be easily dragged back to it's initial location.  When item 'A' is dragged over item 'B', 'B' moves to 'A' old spot.  However', moving 'A' back over 'B' doesn't return 'B' to its original spot.  This is probably fixable, but I haven't looked at the code yet.

Answer (score 1):

1) If the items you do not want changeable are all at the top and/or bottom of the list, you can create those items outside of the list, thereby allowing only of the sorting of OTHER items and preserving the rankings of the immutable ones.

2) Can you use the "stop" event to check that the rankings of the ones you want has been preserved? ie, check that there are still only 3 items above the 4th ranking item, and if not, move the new "4th" below the one that has an immutable rank of 4th? Basically, force a re-shifting of items after the item has been dragged into an illegal spot?

Comment: (1) is not an option; frozen items can appear in the middle.  (2) is an option, although I'm worried about the amount of flickering that re-adjustment will cause.  Even the simple swapping approach is noticeable.

Comment: I definitely hear that... how do you feel about a smoother transition, where the item gently eases into the new spot? I realize this is not as ideal... will keep thinking about it... it's an interesting problem!

Comment: What about, if instead of doing a hard swap (as in your jsfiddle example), you did a smooth transition? slowly slide the item that is getting displaced into its new location, and use the drop handler to allow the new item to be dropped into that spot?

Comment: I think that If the frozen item will allways be in the end, the option 1 is the best solution. Because the drop placeholder won't lie to the user, and will be less checks. But of course, only if the frozen item must be at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Update 2023:

```
//html
<div id="example6" class="list-group col">
    <div class="list-group-item">Item 1</div>
    <div class="list-group-item" style="">Item 2</div>
    <div class="list-group-item" style="">Item 3</div>
    <div class="list-group-item bg-danger filtered" style="">Filtered</div>
    <div class="list-group-item" style="">Item 4</div>                  
    <div class="list-group-item" draggable="false" style="">Item 5</div></div>
//js
new Sortable(example6, {
    filter: '.filtered', // 'filtered' class is not draggable
    animation: 150
});
```