# Attempting to "pin" a sortable jQuery <li>, unexpected behavior

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, web

### The Story

So I'm attempting to create a sortable list where each item can be "pinned" on a button press or other event, causing the pinned item to become undraggable and keeping it's position in the list. So far I've gotten to the point of adding a class to the sortable element with this:

```
$(".test").click(function(){
  //alert($(event.target).parent("li").text());        
  $(event.target).parent("li").toggleClass("static");
});
```

Which works by binding this click function to the a.test element in each li.free

```
<ul id="sortable">
<li class="free">oranges<a href="#" class="test">click</a></li>
<li class="free">apples<a href="#" class="test">click</a></li>
<li class="free">bananas<a href="#" class="test">click</a></li>
<li class="free">pineapples<a href="#" class="test">click</a></li>
<li class="free">grapes<a href="#" class="test">click</a></li>
<li class="free">pears<a href="#" class="test">click</a></li>
<li class="free">mango<a href="#" class="test">click</a></li>
</ul>​
```

This toggles the ".static" class in the li which should allow the sortable function to ignore items marked as such. I account for the changes with the change handler in the function:

```
$("#sortable").sortable({
  items: ':not(.static)',
  start: function(){
    $('.static', this).each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.data('pos', $this.index());
    });
  },
  change: function(){
    $sortable = $(this);
    $statics = $('.static', this).detach();
    $helper = $('<li></li>').prependTo(this);
    $statics.each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        var target = $this.data('pos');

        $this.insertAfter($('li', $sortable).eq(target));
    });
    $helper.remove();
  }
}).disableSelection();
```

### The Problem

So the issue I'm having is that, while  it does act as expected at first, the pinned elements can be moved by moving the active sortable elements above them thus pushing the pinned element down the list. Any thoughts would be welcome.

### The jsFiddle

Click [here](http://jsfiddle.net/miguet/PQrqS/136/) for the jsFiddle example.

### edit!!!

So in further testing I found another issue... this script doesn't appear to work in Firefox, at all. I've got other work to move to so I'll check back here in a few hours, thanks for any advice you can offer.

Comment: As a sidenote, the upadte option and it's related code is based off DarthJDG's answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4299241/jquery-sortable-lists-and-fixed-locked-items) with the major difference being that I want to do this on the fly rather than statically

Comment: i think the problem is the event variable in your click handler, see http://jsfiddle.net/PQrqS/137/

Comment: Thanks for your response svillamayor, but unfortunately that doesn't seem to have fixed the bug. Replicating the bug is a little tricky but here goes. Try "pinning" the first three elements in the list and then try to drag the topmost pinned item to near the bottom of the list, and let go. [I see this](http://i.imgur.com/tja7e.png)

Answer (score 0):

just pass the event argument on click event like this:

```
$(".test").click(function(event){
        //alert($(event.target).parent("li").text());        
        $(event.target).parent("li").toggleClass("static");
    });
```

i think this is it