# How make Div fixed in jquery ui sortable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

i'm applying jquery sortable on list of divs below is my code

```
                    <div class="area_options">
                      <div class="area_top"><p>At the bar</p></div>
                      <div class="area_list"><p>Appetizers</p></div>
                      <div class="area_list"><p>Beverages</p></div>
                      <div class="area_list"><p>Cocktail</p></div>
                    </div>
```

I want to make area_top div fixed which is heading of container.And apply sortable on the base of are_list div only.

Now sortable working fine and are apply also on area_top div.

How i can make area_top div fixed?

Thanks

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shuklendu/UAcC7/17/) as well as the include/exclude items section [here](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#items)

Comment: Look here. This should answer your question.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4299241/jquery-sortable-lists-and-fixed-locked-items

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the option `items` of the sortable() to `.area_list`

The documentation of the property [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-items) says:

> Specifies which items inside the element should be sortable.

EDIT: With your current html, the javascript would be like this :

```
$(".area_options").sortable({ items: ".area_list" });
```

Comment: how specify area_list  class