# jqueryui extension 'fixedsortable.js': how to get fixed elements in a nested, fixedsortable structure to respond properly in the larger context

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable, fixed

Observe the following example:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui-1.10.0.js"></script>
    <script src="fixedsortable.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul class="list-1">
      <li class="fixed">Fruits</li><!-- responds as expected (it lives at the top level)-->
      <li>
        <ul class="list-2">
          <li class="fixed">-Tomatoes are fruits too!</li><!-- not as expected, should act like a handle to sort the entire list of tomatoes within the list of fruits (as if it were a child element of a sortable item) -->
          <li>--cherry tomatoes</li>
          <li>--plum tomatoes</li>
          <li>--roma tomatoes</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>-oranges</li>
      <li>-cherries</li>
      <li>-bananas</li>
    </ul>
    <script>
      $('[class*="list-"]').fixedsortable({
        fixed: ".fixed"
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

fixedsortable.js extension can be found here:
[question #4299241](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4299241/jquery-sortable-lists-and-fixed-locked-items)

I found the following about the fixedsortable extension:

```
...

},

_mouseStart: function( event ) { 

  for(var i=0;i<this.options.fixed.length;++i) {
    var num = this.options.fixed[i];
    var elem = this.items[num];

    if(event.target == elem.item.get(0)) return false;
  }

  return $.ui.sortable.prototype._mouseStart.apply(this,arguments);
},

...
```

I tried walking up the DOM via `event.target.parentNode` to find any other sortables and passing whatever is found as a jquery in place of `this` along with `arguments` to the prototype, otherwise returning false when the document is reached, but it's not clear how it should be done or if this is the correct approach.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it has been a few late nights since the question was asked so I figure a followup is in order...

After studying jquery a bit I found it easy enough to write my own plugin. Though jquery-ui is a nice api to drop and go, I found the process of trying to customizing it to be a bit cumbersome. I was able to accomplish the specific behavior I want with a few of my own plugins and much less overhead. Also I will not have to try to maintain code that I did not write to begin with. :)

In case anyone is interested, the solution provided by fixedsortable.js breaks event propagation with `return false;` from an extended _mousestart wrapper where the 'fixed' status of the target is tested. A proper solution involves restricting event binding to only those element which are not fixed, not by binding to every sortable target and then trying to restrict event propagation on fixed targets. This is the approach that I used in my plug.