# jQuery UI Sortable dynamic fixed items

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I need some help with getting some items to stay in place in a jquery UI sortable.

I know about [JQuery sortable lists and fixed/locked items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4299241/jquery-sortable-lists-and-fixed-locked-items) and it does work quite nicely, the problem is that this works fine if you're not adding items. If you add more items to the sortable you have to call .fixedsortable again and I'd like to avoid that.
Here's an example of my setup:

```
<ul>
<li></li>
<li class="fixed"></li>
<li></li>
<li class="fixed"></li>
<li></li>
</ul>
```

I need the "fixed" class to remain in place when sorting.

Answer (score 1):

You can make container element `sortable` so that you will not have to worry about new elements:

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fcKE5/1/)

HTML:

```
<ul id="container">
    <li>1</li>
    <li class="fixed">2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li class="fixed">4</li>
    <li>5</li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
 $("#container").sortable();
```

Comment: my problem is that i need the class "fixed" to stay in place when reordering the other elements

Comment: but that way they still get moved when you drag around other elements

Comment: Sadly that one didn't work with dynamically added items either.

Comment: You simply need to recalculate `correctIndex/correctItems` arrays whenever you add a new item.

Comment: I have some progress with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4299241/jquery-sortable-lists-and-fixed-locked-items . I managed to get the fixedsortable working fine, until I delete an item from the sortable.
I tried doing .sortable("refresh") but that returns an error