# How to add new elements to jQuery Sortable with fixed elements?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I came across a post ([jQuery UI Sortable dynamic fixed items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17512895/jquery-ui-sortable-dynamic-fixed-items)) from some time ago while trying to find an answer to my current question. Unfortunately, the OP's question was not really answered. Please do forgive me for therefore re-opening the original question.

I have a jQuery Sortable with 'fixed' elements:

```
<ul id='sortable'>
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li class='fixed'>item 3</li>
  <li>item 4</li>
</ul>
```

I have excluded the fixed items from sorting by using DarthJDG's suggestions in this post ([JQuery sortable lists and fixed/locked items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4299241/jquery-sortable-lists-and-fixed-locked-items)) and everything is working nicely.

When I dynamically add or remove an item to the sortable, I would like to have the position(s) of the fixed element(s) honoured.

So, after an add event this would be the desired list:

```
<ul id='sortable'>
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>NEW ITEM</li>
  <li class='fixed'>item 3</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>item 4</li>
</ul>
```

Or after deleting item 2 from the original list, this would be the desired outcome:

```
<ul id='sortable'>
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 4</li>
  <li class='fixed'>item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Any help on the matter would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: here's a fiddle of what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/1cucuj91/

Answer (score 0):

I love it when an answer to a problem comes to you after a good night's sleep. This is what I came up with:

```
function add(afterthisitem) {

    var newitem = $('<li/>').text('NEW ITEM');
    var sortable = $('#sortable');

    $('.fixed',sortable).each(function(){
        var el = $(this);
        el.data('pos',el.index());
    })

    $(afterthisitem).after(newitem);

    $('li',sortable).each( function(index) {
        var el = $(this);
        var pos = el.data('pos');
        if (el.hasClass('fixed') && pos!=index) {
            el.detach();
            el.insertBefore($('li', sortable).eq( pos ));
        }   
    })

}
```

The answer was hidden in DarthJDG's earlier answer with the technique of detaching and inserting at the correct position. The function above even works when you would have two fixed items after another.