# How can I combine jQuery sortable UI with static captions for the placeholders?

Tags: css, jquery-ui

I have a sortable set of pictures, implemented with jQuery UI. I would like to have each of the pictures within a box and with a caption at the top. The boxes and their captions should not move when pictures are sorted. Is there an easy way to do this?

EDIT: I have been investigating a bit and I found an approach that could do the trick. It consists on locking down some items on their locations using

```
class: static
```

(see the second answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4299241/jquery-sortable-lists-and-fixed-locked-items)) and this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8mcggjsr/1/).

Unfortunately, when I insert images into the list, it does not work well anymore: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8mcggjsr/).

Comment: It'd be helpfull for those trying to help you if you share the boilerplate HTML and CSS you have so far...

Comment: Sorry @TJ, see the two demos above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following little code did the trick:

**HTML**

```
<div class="sortableDiv">
    <ul id="sortable">
        <li class="ui-state-default">
            <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s">
                <image src="http://t1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ0wAliOPQ_saAtWhNhhPajglDjIZVrnO19MXaYS0Doum-yztJ_CA"/>
            </span>
        </li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">
            <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s">
                <image src="http://t1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ0wAliOPQ_saAtWhNhhPajglDjIZVrnO19MXaYS0Doum-yztJ_CA"/>
            </span>
        </li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">
            <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s">
                <image src="http://t1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ0wAliOPQ_saAtWhNhhPajglDjIZVrnO19MXaYS0Doum-yztJ_CA"/>
            </span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="contentDiv">
    <ul id="content">
        <li class="ui-state-default">
            Item Description 1
        </li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">
            Item Description 2
        </li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">
            Item Description 3
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.sortableDiv,.contentDiv {
    float:left;
}

#content {
    list-style-type:none;
    line-height:88px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#sortable {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#sortable li {
    padding-left:2em;
    width:65px;
    margin:5px;
}

#sortable li span {
    position:relative;
    margin-left:-1.3em;
}

image {
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
}
```

**JQuery**

```
$(function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
});
```

And some CSS given in the demo link.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/r79eon6h/1/)

[Updated DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/r79eon6h/4/)

[Updated DEMO-1](http://jsfiddle.net/r79eon6h/6/)

Comment: Thanks Parkash for your help. Unfortunately your code is similar to the one I currently have. What I want is being able to move/sort only the pictures, while leaving the boxes and labels where they are (i.e., boxes and labels should not move, only the pictures)

Comment: Thanks again, @ParkashKumar. That works, but it is not exactly what I want. I would like to have the captions above the sortable items, rather than on the side. Could that be solved using your approach?

Comment: @Humberto - See 'Updated DEMO-1'. Does it fulfill your requirement now?

Comment: Thanks @ParkashKumar! This is a rather simple solution that uses only css. I like it!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like what you need is a combination of draggable and droppables widgets rather than sortable. I'd call it "swappable" :P

You can achieve this by swapping the images on drop event as shown below:

```js
$("#swappable img").draggable({
  revert: "invalid",
  zIndex: 1
});
$("#swappable .placeholder").droppable({
  snap: true,
  snapMode: "inner",
  drop: function(event, ui) {
    var $existing = $(this).find("img.ui-draggable");
    if ($existing)
    /* droppable already contain an image, append it to the parent of
        dropped item. */
      ui.draggable.parent().append($existing);

    ui.draggable.css({ // reset the positioning applied by widget
      top: 0,
      left: 0
    }).appendTo(this);
  }
});
```

```css
#swappable {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#swappable li {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: cream;
}
#swappable li span {
  /*style anyway you want*/
}
#swappable li img {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
#swappable li .placeholder {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<ul id="swappable">
  <li>
    <div class="placeholder">
      <img src="http://i46.tinypic.com/2epim8j.jpg" />
    </div>
    <span>
       Item Description 1
     </span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="placeholder">
      <img src="http://i49.tinypic.com/28vepvr.jpg" />
    </div>
    <span>
       Item Description 2
     </span>

  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="placeholder">
      <img src="http://i50.tinypic.com/f0ud01.jpg" />
    </div>
    <span>
       Item Description 3
     </span>
  </li>
</ul>
```