# jQuery UI sortable - Sort around stationary items

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

jQuery UI sortable allows some items in a list to be sortable, while preventing other items from being sortable. But when dragging a sortable item, the items that are not sortable can still be knocked out of position.

Is there a way to always keep certain items in stationary positions, while allowing the sortable items to flow around the stationary items? For example, if item FIVE is dragged to position 3, then item THREE should drop to position 5, leaving item FOUR in position 4.

https://jsfiddle.net/jimbertelsen/heksbeoq/6/

```
$(function() {
    $('#SortableList').sortable({
        items: '> li.canMove',
        axis: 'y'
    });
});

<ol id="SortableList">
    <li class="canMove">ONE (Can move from position 1)</li>
    <li class="neverMove">TWO (Should never leave position 2)</li>
    <li class="canMove">THREE (Can move from position 3)</li>
    <li class="neverMove">FOUR (Should never leave position 4)</li>
    <li class="canMove">FIVE (Can move from position 5)</li>
    <li class="canMove">SIX (Can move from position 6)</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4299241/jquery-sortable-lists-and-fixed-locked-items

Comment: @user1778606 -- Thanks a bunch! Problem solved.