# Fixed items within jQuery sortable list

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a sortable list as follows:

```
   <div id = "sortable">

         <div class = "sortableItem day">Monday</div>
         <div class = "sortableItem" id="result1">Hotel 1</div>
         <div class = "sortableItem" id="result2">Hotel 2</div>
         <div class = "sortableItem" id="result3">Hotel 3</div>
         <div class = "sortableItem" id="result4">Hotel 4</div>
         <div class = "sortableItem" id="result5">Hotel 5</div>

         <div class = "sortableItem day">Tuesday</div>
         <div class = "sortableItem" id="result6"></div>
         <div class = "sortableItem" id="result7"></div>
         <div class = "sortableItem" id="result8"></div>
         <div class = "sortableItem" id="result9"></div>
         <div class = "sortableItem" id="result10"></div>


          <div class = "sortableItem day">Wednesday</div>
         <div class = "sortableItem" id="result11"></div>
         <div class = "sortableItem" id="result12"></div>
         <div class = "sortableItem" id="result13"></div>
         <div class = "sortableItem" id="result14"></div>
         <div class = "sortableItem" id="result15"></div>


         <div class = "sortableItem day">Thursday</div>
         <div class = "sortableItem" id="result16"></div>
         <div class = "sortableItem" id="result17"></div>
         <div class = "sortableItem" id="result18"></div>
         <div class = "sortableItem" id="result19"></div>
         <div class = "sortableItem" id="result20"></div>


         <div class = "sortableItem day">Friday</div>
         <div class = "sortableItem" id="result21"></div>
         <div class = "sortableItem" id="result22"></div>
         <div class = "sortableItem" id="result23"></div>
         <div class = "sortableItem" id="result24"></div>
         <div class = "sortableItem" id="result25"></div>

      </div>

      <script>

        $(function() {
          $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
        });

      </script>
```

This works fine, except that the days of the week divs should not be sortable. They should be fixed and the other items should sort around them.

So for example, if I drag #result6 up into Monday, then #result5 should drop down into Tuesday as the div containing Tuesday should hold its position. Is this possible with jQuery's sortable or do I need to consider a different method here?

Answer (score 1):

You can disable sorting to some items by adding `items: "div:not(.days)"` to [option item](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-items)

**Note:** Some of the days of the week `divs` have class `day` and some have `days`. I used `days` on all for the snippet below. And remove `sortableItem` class on days

```js
$("#sortable").sortable({
  items: "div:not(.days)",
  stop: function(event, ui) {
    $(this).find('.days').each(function(i) {
      $(this).insertBefore('.sortableItem:eq(' + (i * 5) + ')');
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.days {
  background-color: red;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="sortable">

  <div class="days">Monday</div>
  <div class="sortableItem" id="result1">Hotel 1</div>
  <div class="sortableItem" id="result2">Hotel 2</div>
  <div class="sortableItem" id="result3">Hotel 3</div>
  <div class="sortableItem" id="result4">Hotel 4</div>
  <div class="sortableItem" id="result5">Hotel 5</div>

  <div class="days">Tuesday</div>
  <div class="sortableItem" id="result6">Hotel 6</div>
  <div class="sortableItem" id="result7">Hotel 7</div>
  <div class="sortableItem" id="result8">Hotel 8</div>
  <div class="sortableItem" id="result9">Hotel 9</div>
  <div class="sortableItem" id="result10">Hotel 10</div>

  <div class="days">Wednesday</div>
  <div class="sortableItem" id="result11">Hotel 11</div>
  <div class="sortableItem" id="result12">Hotel 12</div>
  <div class="sortableItem" id="result13">Hotel 13</div>
  <div class="sortableItem" id="result14">Hotel 14</div>
  <div class="sortableItem" id="result15">Hotel 15</div>

  <div class="days">Thursday</div>
  <div class="sortableItem" id="result16">Hotel 16</div>
  <div class="sortableItem" id="result17">Hotel 17</div>
  <div class="sortableItem" id="result18">Hotel 18</div>
  <div class="sortableItem" id="result19">Hotel 19</div>
  <div class="sortableItem" id="result20">Hotel 20</div>

  <div class="days">Friday</div>
  <div class="sortableItem" id="result21">Hotel 21</div>
  <div class="sortableItem" id="result22">Hotel 22</div>
  <div class="sortableItem" id="result23">Hotel 23</div>
  <div class="sortableItem" id="result24">Hotel 24</div>
  <div class="sortableItem" id="result25">Hotel 25</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did find something similar but the only thing it doesn't do is to keep the index of the '.days' elements the same. So for example, "Tuesday" is at sortable.children[6] and I want it to stay there regardless of how the items are sorted around it. So If I drag #result6 up above "Tuesday" then #result5 should be forced down below Tuesday. Does that make sense?!

Comment: Also I did see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4299241/jquery-sortable-lists-and-fixed-locked-items ... but I cannot seem to source jQuery's fixedsortable CDN...

Comment: Are you trying to have 5 *sortables* per day?

Comment: I saw that you already figured it out :) But I would like to share my code. Just change the position of `days` div on every 5th sortable div

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out (well thanks to this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/PQrqS/1/ I found in [JQuery sortable lists and fixed/locked items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4299241/jquery-sortable-lists-and-fixed-locked-items))!

```
$(function() {          

$('#sortable').sortable({
items: ':not(.day)',
start: function(){
    $('.day', this).each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.data('pos', $this.index());
    });
},
change: function(){
    $sortable = $(this);
    $statics = $('.day', this).detach();
    $helper = $('<div></div>').prependTo(this);
    $statics.each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        var target = $this.data('pos');

        $this.insertAfter($('div', $sortable).eq(target));
    });
    $helper.remove();
}
})
})
```

This works absolutely perfectly :)