# JQuery Sortable set item to an index programmatically

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a JQuery sortable (1.7.1 can change if necessary) list like so:

```
<ul id='pl'>
  <li class='item'>1</li>
  <li class='item locked'>2</li>
  <li class='item'>3</li>
  <li class='item'>4</li>
  <li class='item'>5</li>
</ul>
```

The second item is locked so if item 5 is tried to be moved in slot 2 it will go in slot 3 instead and if tried to be moved in slot 1 then existing item in slot 1 drops to 3 and item 5 goes to 1.

The implementation logic is easy but what I need to know is if there is any programmatic way of moving items around that would include the animations.

Did find this one already [Moving an item programmatically with jQuery sortable while still triggering events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911124/jquery-sortable-move-item-programatically) but not sure if the 'sortupdate' event would simulate a drag and drop or if it would even work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**This worked perfectly.**

Follow the steps and **include this**:

```
    $el.fadeOut(1000, function(){
        $el.insertAfter($el.next());

        $el.fadeIn(1000);
    });
```

**Like this** *(setting the id of the li tag of course)*:

```
jQuery(".templateMoveUp").on("click", function(){   
    $el = jQuery("#" + $(this).attr("id") + "_logTemplate");
    $el.fadeOut(1000, function(){
        $el.insertBefore($el.prev());
        $el.fadeIn(1000);
    });
});
jQuery(".templateMoveDown").on("click", function(){ 
    $el = jQuery("#" + $(this).attr("id") + "_logTemplate");
    $el.fadeOut(1000, function(){
        $el.insertAfter($el.next());
        $el.fadeIn(1000);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

After a quick look on jQuery's Sortable source code it doesn't seem that such functionality is built in at this point (would be a good addition to it I'd think). Anyhow, a quick workaround I used for now in case anyone ever has the same issue:

```
        $el.fadeOut(1000, function(){
            $el.insertAfter($el.next());

            $el.fadeIn(1000);
        });
```

It somewhat clearly indicates an item moving from one spot to another.

Here's the complete code to the above problem if anyone comes around to the exact same issue.

1- Register these 2 events in the Sortable init like so:

```
start: function(event,ui){$(ui.item).data('initialPos', $(ui.item).offset().top)},
handle: ".drag",
stop: lockedRearrange,
```

2-

```
var lockedRearrange = function(event, ui){

    //block ordering while the current item is rearranged
    $('.drag', event.target).removeClass('drag').addClass('blockdrag');

    var $el = $(ui.item);
    var directionUp = (ui.absolutePosition.top < $el.data('initialPos')) ? true : false ;

    _rearrange($el, directionUp, $el.data('initialPos'));
};

var _rearrange = function($el, directionUp, initialPos){
    if ($el.offset().top == initialPos) {
        $('.blockdrag', $el.parent()).removeClass('blockdrag').addClass('drag');
        return;
    }

    var $knockEl = (directionUp) ? $el.next() : $el.prev();

    if ($knockEl.hasClass('locked')) {
        $el.fadeOut(1000, function(){
            (directionUp) ? $el.insertAfter($knockEl) : $el.insertBefore($knockEl);

            $el.fadeIn(1000, function(){
                _rearrange($el, directionUp, initialPos);
            });
        });
    }else
        _rearrange($knockEl, directionUp, initialPos);
};
```