# How can I keep jQueryUI sortable list sorted?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have several related lists that are managed by jQueryUI's Sortable module.  At startup, each list is sorted lexically, and I would like to keep that order as items are moved between the lists.  Right now I'm just resorting each list as things are dropped into them, but I'd to add some animation to the process.  Here's a fiddle showing what I'd doing right now:  http://jsfiddle.net/samwyse/khezu7xh/

I want to replace the following code with something that uses animations:

```
// Update code for the actual sortable lists
$(this).sortChildren();
```

I'm guessing that I need to check the dropped item and if it's less than the preceding item, float it up the list, or if it's greater than the following item, float it down.  I've not done any animations before, so I'm unsure how to proceed.  The only code I've found that does anything similar doesn't actually reorder the list, it just changes to top attribute of the items so they look right.

Comment: It just occurred to me that I could modify the logic of Sortable to only "open up" the correct target slot, and have the dropped item land there.  But I'm not sure how to do that, either.  :(

Comment: did you check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911124/moving-an-item-programmatically-with-jquery-sortable-while-still-triggering-even  | http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928002/jquery-sortable-set-item-to-an-index-programmatically

Comment: Thanks for the pointers.  I've created a new fiddle that does part of what I want.  Now to add animation!  http://jsfiddle.net/samwyse/zjrvLuty/