# How to fix a div in sortable grid in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

[image: sortable hexagons]

In the above image all the hexagons are movable, except the blue centre hexagon. I want to fix the blue hexagon at the centre, while any other hexagon can move to anywhere. But I don't understand how to do this. For more clarity, I want to fix the blue hexagon at 7th position.

My code is

```
$("#sortable").sortable({
    cursor: 'move',
    items: 'div.sort',
}).disableSelection();
```

`HTML`

```
 <div class="col-sm-12 margin-top-100 margin-left-100" id="sortable">
    <div id="c_1" class="hexagon hexagon2 sort">
        <div class="hexagon-in1">
           <div class="hexagon-in2">
              <div class="inner inner-left text-center"><i class="fa fa-eye"> </i></div><div class="inner inner-right text-center"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></div>
              </div>
           </div>
         </div>
     <div id="c_2"  class="hexagon hexagon2 sort">
       <div class="hexagon-in1">
         <div class="hexagon-in2">
        <div class="inner inner-left text-center"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></div><div class="inner inner-right text-center"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
   <div id="c_3"  class="hexagon hexagon2 sort">
    <div class="hexagon-in1">
    <div class="hexagon-in2">
        <div class="inner inner-left text-center"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></div><div class="inner inner-right text-center"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="c_4"  class="hexagon hexagon2 sort">
<div class="hexagon-in1">
    <div class="hexagon-in2">
        <div class="inner inner-left text-center"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></div><div class="inner inner-right text-center"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></div>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>

<div id="c_5"  class="hexagon hexagon2 sort">
<div class="hexagon-in1">
    <div class="hexagon-in2">
        <div class="inner inner-left text-center"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></div><div class="inner inner-right text-center"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></div>
    </div>
 </div>
 </div>
<div id="c_6"  class="hexagon hexagon2 sort">
<div class="hexagon-in1">
    <div class="hexagon-in2">
        <div class="inner inner-left text-center"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></div><div class="inner inner-right text-center"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
<div id="c_7"  class="hexagon hexagon2" >
<div class="hexagon-in1">
    <div class="hexagon-in2" id="kinglinkr">
        <div class="inner inner-left text-center"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></div><div class="inner inner-right text-center"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i></div>
    </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 <div id="c_8"  class="hexagon hexagon2 sort">
  <div class="hexagon-in1">
    <div class="hexagon-in2">
        <div class="inner inner-left text-center"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></div><div class="inner inner-right text-center"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="c_9"  class="hexagon hexagon2 sort">
<div class="hexagon-in1">
    <div class="hexagon-in2">
        <div class="inner inner-left text-center"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></div><div class="inner inner-right text-center"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<div id="c_10"  class="hexagon hexagon2 sort">
<div class="hexagon-in1">
    <div class="hexagon-in2">
        <div class="inner inner-left text-center"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></div><div class="inner inner-right text-center"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></div>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div id="c_11"  class="hexagon hexagon2 sort">
<div class="hexagon-in1">
    <div class="hexagon-in2">
        <div class="inner inner-left text-center"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></div><div class="inner inner-right text-center"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div id="c_12"  class="hexagon hexagon2 sort">
 <div class="hexagon-in1">
    <div class="hexagon-in2">
        <div class="inner inner-left text-center"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></div><div class="inner inner-right text-center"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></div>
    </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 <div id="c_13"  class="hexagon hexagon2 sort">
 <div class="hexagon-in1">
    <div class="hexagon-in2">
        <div class="inner inner-left text-center"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></div><div class="inner inner-right text-center"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></div>
    </div>
 </div>
 </div>

 <div id="c_14"  class="hexagon hexagon2 sort">
 <div class="hexagon-in1">
    <div class="hexagon-in2">
        <div class="inner inner-left text-center"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></div><div class="inner inner-right text-center"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></div>
    </div>
 </div>
 </div>
<div id="c_15"  class="hexagon hexagon2 sort">
<div class="hexagon-in1">
    <div class="hexagon-in2">
        <div class="inner inner-left text-center"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></div><div class="inner inner-right text-center"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></div>
    </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 <div id="c_16"  class="hexagon hexagon2 sort">
 <div class="hexagon-in1">
    <div class="hexagon-in2">
        <div class="inner inner-left text-center"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></div><div class="inner inner-right text-center"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></div>
    </div>
 </div>
 </div>

 </div>
```

Please help me. Your help would be appreciated. Thanks.

i added this on fiddle but don't know why drag is not working

https://jsfiddle.net/vinie23/2jsqmgw2/

Comment: can you share jsfiddle version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for reply. I solved it using following code

```
var fixed=function(event,ui) {
    var thisindex = $(ui.helper).index(fixed);         
    var fixed = $("#c_7");           
    var index = $("#sortable .hexagon").index(fixed);
    var targetindex = 7;
    if(index !== targetindex) {         
        if(index > targetindex ) {
            fixed.prev().insertAfter(fixed); //move it up by one position
        } else if(index==(targetindex-1) && thisindex>targetindex) {
            //don't move it at all
        } else {
            fixed.next().insertBefore(fixed); //move it down by one position
        }
    } else if(index==targetindex && thisindex>targetindex) {
        fixed.prev().insertAfter(fixed); //move it up by one position
    }       
}

    var fixd=function(e, tr) {
    var sorted_id=tr.item.get(0).id;
    get_sort();
    };

    $("#sortable").sortable({
    cursor: 'move',
    items: 'div.sort',
    cancel:'#c_7',
    change: fixed,
    stop:fixd
    }).disableSelection();
```

Reference [Forcing an item to remain in place in a jQuery UI Sortable list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529269/forcing-an-item-to-remain-in-place-in-a-jquery-ui-sortable-list)

Answer (score 0):

Give extra class for blue hexagons  and use `items` like:

```
$(".sortable").sortable({
      items: "li:not(.unsortable)" //unsortable extra class for blue
    });
```

Comment: by using your code blue hexagon won't sortable but when i drag 8th position hexagon and place it at 6 position then blue hexagon position will also change to 8th. I want it still on 7th position.

Comment: please see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4299241/jquery-sortable-lists-and-fixed-locked-items

Answer (score 0):

There is a slightly better way to solve this.
You need to use a grid instead of a list and then you can fix the position of an element by declaring where the element should be arranged with CSS:

```
.fixed-element {
   grid-column-start: 1;
   grid-column-end: 1;
   grid-row-start: 1;
   grid-row-end: 1;
}
```

Make sure not to forget to disable the sortable option of the fixed element:

```
$('.fixed-element').sortable({ disabled: false });
```